# Fixed length File from Sqoop

Tags: hadoop, sqoop

Is it possible to import a file in fixed length from DB2 database using sqoop import? I have not found anything so far in sqoop documentation.

Thanks
Arani

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for importing column of a fixed length from any database you can use free form query like below

sqoop import --connect jdbc:oracle:* --username name --password pwd -e " select substr(COL1,1,4000),substr(COL2,1,4000),COL3 from TABLE_NAME where \$CONDITIONS" --target-dir /user/username/table_name --as-textfile -m 1